# Intercept an image before it's uploaded to Media Gallery

Tags: php, wordpress, gif

I've got a WordPress website where I need to have some posts with gifs as thumbnails. After researching this topic a bit I realized that I have to intercept the gif before it's passed into Media Gallery. I have no idea where to even begin as I haven't found any hooks to hook in.

How can I pass the gif, that's being uploaded, to a custom function? Is there a way to do it in WordPress?

Comment: You might have better luck on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

put this function in ur functions.php of ur theme.

```
function custom_upload_filter( $file )
{
    // this line catch the name of the current upload file
    // and check the filetype
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype($file['name']);

    // then check the extension file if it isn't a gif file set the $file["error"] with an advertissement
    if( $filetype["ext"] != "gif" || $filetype["ext"] != "GIF )
        $file["error"] = "Please upload a file with a 'gif' extension !";

    return $file;
}
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter' );
```

ps: after add this functions to ur theme, u can't upload anymore other file than 'gif' file

I hope that help u.

Comment: Thanks, so by modifying the "only gifs" conditional statement I will be able to perform one action on gif files and the default action on other files right?

Comment: What do u want to do with the gif after it was upload ?

Comment: Break it down into frames, crop every frame to a certain size and then merge the cropped frames into a gif again. After that I have to make WordPress recognize the new gif as a Media Library item. This will allow me to upload gifs and set them as thumbnails without problems.